# Why does an xml element's text type vary from str to unicode?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, unicode

I'm on Python 2.7.12.

When I parse the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<data>value</data>
```

and I check the type of the element's text via:

```
>>> from xml.etree import ElementTree
>>> type(ElementTree.parse('test.xml').getroot().text)
<type 'str'>
```

I'm surprised to see it's a `str` - what I expected is a `unicode`. Only when I introduce non-ASCII characters to the XML file, as for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<data>valuè</data>
```

then the text is stored as `unicode`:

```
>>> type(ElementTree.parse('test.xml').getroot().text)
<type 'unicode'>
```

First of all, why does the `xml` API exhibit this kind of inconsistency and secondly how can I force it to always use `unicode`?

Comment: I can't say why it is like that, but to force unicode, you can always `unicode(ElementTree.parse('test.xml').getroot().text)`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XMLParser class in ElementTree.py (from the xml library) has a little helper function that tries to convert to ascii if possible, but returns unicode if it can't do that:

```
def _fixtext(self, text):
    # convert text string to ascii, if possible
    try:
        return text.encode("ascii")
    except UnicodeError:
        return text
```

This is why you'll see the types change.

Here is a link to the source code:
https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/xml/etree/ElementTree.py#l1519

Comment: Can you post link to the actual source so that people can verify themselves? Thanks